# Is it conceivable to have a DApp that doesn't issue tokens?

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to nail down my explanations to people when they ask about Ethereum, and I'm trying to think of applications that wouldn't benefit from dispersing a token for some reason or another.

Comment: Sure; an obvious example I'm working on at the moment is a name registrar and resolution service.

Comment: Are you talking about DAOs maybe rather than DApps?

Answer (score 3):

DApp stands for 'Decentralized Application'The characterising feature of a Dapp is that there is no reliance on a central server. There is no requirement for a Dapp to issue tokens or to be financial. BitTorrent probably qualifies as a Dapp.

- DApp = Decentralized Application
- DAO = Decentralized Autonomous Organization
- DAC = Decentralized Autonomous Corporation

See [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/05/06/daos-dacs-das-and-more-an-incomplete-terminology-guide/) blogpost for a more detailed discussion of the above terminology.